# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS install VMware 12 Kernel module updater

Tags: vmware

[image]

How to solve this?

And the log content is this:

```
2017-07-23T13:46:45.958+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Log for VMware Workstation pid=11218 version=12.0.0 build=build-2985596 option=Release
2017-07-23T13:46:45.958+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2017-07-23T13:46:45.958+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2017-07-23T13:46:45.958+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Host is Linux 4.8.0-36-generic Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
2017-07-23T13:46:45.957+08:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2017-07-23T13:46:45.957+08:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2017-07-23T13:46:45.957+08:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2017-07-23T13:46:45.957+08:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2017-07-23T13:46:45.957+08:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2017-07-23T13:46:45.957+08:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2017-07-23T13:46:45.957+08:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.041+08:00| vthread-4| W115: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-11218.log
2017-07-23T13:46:46.049+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.049+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Created new pathsHash.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.049+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.8.0-36-generic to "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.049+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.049+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-07-23T13:46:46.049+08:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.049+08:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-07-23T13:46:46.056+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.056+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.8.0-36-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-07-23T13:46:46.241+08:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/Module.symvers
2017-07-23T13:46:46.241+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.266+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 20864 symbol versions
2017-07-23T13:46:46.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.270+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.270+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.275+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.275+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.276+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.276+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.278+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.278+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.282+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.298+08:00| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2017-07-23T13:46:46.298+08:00| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2017-07-23T13:46:46.322+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.322+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.8.0-36-generic to "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.322+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.322+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-07-23T13:46:46.322+08:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.322+08:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-07-23T13:46:46.329+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.330+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.8.0-36-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-07-23T13:46:46.513+08:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/Module.symvers
2017-07-23T13:46:46.513+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.535+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 20864 symbol versions
2017-07-23T13:46:46.535+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include
2017-07-23T13:46:46.535+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include
2017-07-23T13:46:46.535+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.535+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-07-23T13:46:46.535+08:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.535+08:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-07-23T13:46:46.540+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.540+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.8.0-36-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-07-23T13:46:46.541+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2017-07-23T13:46:46.545+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.545+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.545+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.552+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.552+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.553+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.553+08:00| vthread-4| I125: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.553+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.553+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.553+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-07-23T13:46:46.553+08:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.553+08:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-07-23T13:46:46.558+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.558+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.8.0-36-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-07-23T13:46:46.559+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.559+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.559+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-07-23T13:46:46.559+08:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.559+08:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-07-23T13:46:46.564+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.564+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.8.0-36-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-07-23T13:46:46.565+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.566+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.566+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.8.0-36-generic to "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.566+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.566+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-07-23T13:46:46.566+08:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.566+08:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-07-23T13:46:46.571+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.8.0-36-generic".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.571+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.8.0-36-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-07-23T13:46:46.732+08:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/Module.symvers
2017-07-23T13:46:46.732+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.756+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 20864 symbol versions
2017-07-23T13:46:46.756+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.758+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-07-23T13:46:46.758+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2017-07-23T13:46:46.761+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-07-23T13:46:47.669+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2017-07-23T13:46:47.669+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2017-07-23T13:46:47.676+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2017-07-23T13:46:47.676+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-iWQ9pi/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2017-07-23T13:46:49.344+08:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2017-07-23T13:46:49.346+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2017-07-23T13:46:49.346+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2017-07-23T13:46:49.352+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2017-07-23T13:46:49.352+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-iWQ9pi/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2017-07-23T13:46:50.700+08:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```